# Adding fifth column to Gravity Forms

Tags: css

I've added the CSS and the first four rules work, but the fifth refuses to fall in line. I've been playing at it for a few hours and can't seem to figure it out. Can anyone see a glaring issue that I can't?

```
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_first_fifth,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_second_fifth,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_third_fifth,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fourth_fifth, 
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fifth_fifth{
   margin:0 0 6px 0;
   width:17%;
   }

   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gfield_error.gf_first_fifth,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gfield_error.gf_second_fifth,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gfield_error.gf_third_fifth,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gfield_error.gf_fourth_fifth{
   width:16%;
   }

   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gfield_error.gf_third_fifth {
   margin-right:1%;
   }

   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_first_fifth {
   float:left;
   clear:left!important;
   }

   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_second_fifth,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_third_fifth,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fourth_fifth {
   float:left;
   margin-left:2%;
   clear:none!important;
   }

   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gfield_error.gf_second_fifth,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gfield_error.gf_third_fifth {
   margin-left:3%;
   }

   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_first_fifth input.medium,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_first_fifth input.large,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_first_fifth select.medium,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_first_fifth select.large,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_second_fifth input.medium,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_second_fifth input.large,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_second_fifth select.medium,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_second_fifth select.large,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_third_fifth input.medium,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_third_fifth input.large,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_third_fifth select.medium,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_third_fifth select.large,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fourth_fifth input.medium,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fourth_fifth input.large,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fourth_fifth select.medium,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fourth_fifth select.large, 
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fifth_fifth input.medium,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fifth_fifth input.large,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fifth_fifth select.medium,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fifth_fifth select.large,{
   width:95%;
   }

   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_first_fifth+li.gsection,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_third_fifth+li.gsection {
   padding:12px 0 8px 0;
   }

   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_first_fifth+li.gfield,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_second_fifth+li.gfield,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_third_fifth+li.gfield,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fourth_fifth+li.gfield, 
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fifth_fifth+li.gfield {
   clear:both;
   }

   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_first_fifth+.gform_footer,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_second_fifth+.gform_footer,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_third_fifth+.gform_footer,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fourth_fifth+.gform_footer, 
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fifth_fifth+li.gfield {
   clear:both;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_first_fifth,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_second_fifth,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_third_fifth,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fourth_fifth,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fifth_fifth {
       margin: 0 0 6px 0;
       width: 17%;
   }
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gfield_error.gf_first_fifth,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gfield_error.gf_second_fifth,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gfield_error.gf_third_fifth,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gfield_error.gf_fourth_fifth,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gfield_error.gf_fifth_fifth /* Add This Line for fifth column support */
   
   {
       width: 16%;
   }
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gfield_error.gf_third_fifth {
       margin-right: 1%;
   }
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_first_fifth {
       float: left;
       clear: left!important;
   }
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_second_fifth,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_third_fifth,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fourth_fifth,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fifth_fifth /* Add This for fifth column support */
   
   {
       float: left;
       margin-left: 2%;
       clear: none!important;
   }
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gfield_error.gf_second_fifth,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gfield_error.gf_third_fifth {
       margin-left: 3%;
   }
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_first_fifth input.medium,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_first_fifth input.large,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_first_fifth select.medium,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_first_fifth select.large,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_second_fifth input.medium,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_second_fifth input.large,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_second_fifth select.medium,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_second_fifth select.large,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_third_fifth input.medium,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_third_fifth input.large,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_third_fifth select.medium,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_third_fifth select.large,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fourth_fifth input.medium,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fourth_fifth input.large,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fourth_fifth select.medium,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fourth_fifth select.large,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fifth_fifth input.medium,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fifth_fifth input.large,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fifth_fifth select.medium,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fifth_fifth select.large,
   {
       width: 95%;
   }
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_first_fifth+li.gsection,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_third_fifth+li.gsection {
       padding: 12px 0 8px 0;
   }
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_first_fifth+li.gfield,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_second_fifth+li.gfield,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_third_fifth+li.gfield,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fourth_fifth+li.gfield,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fifth_fifth+li.gfield {
       clear: both;
   }
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_first_fifth+.gform_footer,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_second_fifth+.gform_footer,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_third_fifth+.gform_footer,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fourth_fifth+.gform_footer,
   .gform_wrapper .top_label li.gfield.gf_fifth_fifth+li.gfield {
       clear: both;
   }
```